# Hook into admin_notices after sending mail

Tags: actions, wp-mail, callbacks, notices

In my (admin) plugin I want to display a message using `admin_notices` action on successful sending of mail. Currently it is not displaying. I know this has something to do with the order of events, but I cannot figure out how to structure it so that the message displays.

Currently I'm adding the `admin_notices` action from within an `init` action callback. I'm not sure if this is allowed and therefore this may be the issue. However, if I add it to the `__construct` method, how can I get it to know that the mail has been sent?

Currently my `Send_mail` class looks something like:

```
class Send_mail {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('init', array($this, 'send_mail'), 30 );
    }

    public function send_mail() {
        if (!isset($_POST['send-confirmation-true'])) {
            return;
        }

        // wp_mail() functionality
        // returns true on successful send

        if ($mail_sent == true) {
            add_action('admin_notices', array($this, 'show_admin_notice') );
        }
    }

    public function show_admin_notice() {
        // output admin notice html
    }
}
```

=== EDIT ===

After doing some testing, I've found out that actions called after the following if-statement:

```
if (!isset($_POST['send-confirmation-true'])) {
    return;
}
```

only work if they are hooked to an action that is either `load-(page)` (in my case: `load-post.php`) or before in the action order list. The action I need is `admin_notices` and therefore does not get added. What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: On what page are you calling this? Are you sure `$mail_sent` is true in the if-statement? The `init` action fires before the `admin_notices` action, so this should work.

Comment: `$mail_sent` definitely does return true, I've even tried moving it out of the `if` statement to test (therefore a direct descendent of `send_mail()`) and still the notice does not display. The page it is being called on is post.php.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you want to display a notice after saving a post?

Comment: Yes - it saves then sends the mail. Only on a specific `$_POST` value being set (now added into the example as before I didn't think it was relevant), the `$send_mail()` proceeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This workaround is far from ideal, but it gets the job done.

On `$mail_sent == true` set a post meta. In the `__construct` function add a callback to the `admin_head` action that checks whether the post meta has been set. If yes, delete the post meta and add the `admin_notices` action with the callback to the desired admin notice.

```
class Send_mail {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array($this, 'send_mail'), 30 );
        add_action( 'admin_head', array($this,'check_mail_sent') );
    }

    public function send_mail() {
        if (!isset($_POST['send-confirmation-true'])) {
            return;
        }

        // wp_mail() functionality
        // returns true on successful send

        if ($mail_sent == true) {
            update_post_meta($campaign_id, 'mail_sent', 'yes');
        }
    }

    public function check_mail_sent() {
        global $post;
        $mail_sent = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mail_sent', true );

        if($mail_sent == 'yes') {
            delete_post_meta($post->ID, 'mail_sent');
            add_action('admin_notices', array($this, 'show_admin_notice') );
        } else if ($mail_sent == 'no') {
            // Can handle a mail fail notice here if needed
        }
    }

    public function show_admin_notice() {
        // output admin notice html
    }
}
```